# passing data between html forms using JS or PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a html page that takes a customer's order and submits it to the inventory table in the database. The php file then redirects to a new html page which takes the user's contact information and submits it to the customer contact table in the database. So far so good, but on the first form I calculate the order price. How do I pass this variable to the second form so I can show the customer his/her receipt?

I am new to PHP and am not sure whether to use localStorage or an AJAX request. I would really appreciate an explanation of the pros/cons of using php or javascript (or another method!) to accomplish this. Thanks

EDIT:

Sorry if my question wasn't clear. I've posted code from my html and php pages below. I calculate the price of the pizza in pizzaorder.html, which I would like to pass to pizzaform.html (php file redirects there).

MORE EDITS:

Thanks for the feedback. I've decided to use a session variable to share the price between the html forms. However, when I implement this, my `price` input field shows `<?php echo $_SESSION[` instead of the total calculated in `pizzaorder.html`. Any ideas?

pizzaorder.html (calculates order price)

```
<?php 
require_once("session_start.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

</head>
<script>
/*function receipt(){
var pizzacount = document.getElementById("count").value;
var price = pizzacount*7.99;
alert(price);
}
</script>*/
<body>
<h1>Pizza Order</h1>

<form action="pizzastock.php" method="post">
<h3>Number of pizzas </h3>
<input type="text" name="number" id="count">
<h3>Choose a Topping</h3>
<input type="radio" name="topping" value="jalapeno"> Jalapeno <br>
<input type="radio" name="topping" value="mushroom"> Mushroom<br>
<input type="radio" name="topping" value="anchovy"> Anchovy<br>
<input type="radio" name="topping" value="pineapple"> Pineapple<br>
<input type="radio" name="topping" value="peppers"> Peppers<br>
<input type="radio" name="topping" value="pepperoni"> Pepperroni <br>

<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="receipt()";>

</form>

<?php
if ($_POST){
$num = (int) $_POST['number'];
$price = $num * 7;
$_SESSION["price"]=$price;
}
?>
</body>   
</html>
```

pizzastock.php

```
<?php

require("pizzacnn.php");
$query = "SELECT * FROM `inventory`";
$topping = $_POST['topping'];
$number = $_POST['number'];
if ($query_run=mysqli_query($cnn,$query)){
echo "query successful";
$sql="INSERT INTO inventory (toppings,number) VALUES ('$topping','$number')";
$success = $cnn->query($sql);
if ($success){echo "query recorded successfully";
header("Location:pizzaform.html");}
else {echo "Error:".$sql."<br>".$cnn->error;}
}
else {die("query unsuccessful");}

?>
```

pizzaform.html (displays the receipt to customer)

```
<?php
require_once("session_start.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="pizzaform.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="submit">
<form action="pizza.php" method="post">
<h1>Thanks for Ordering. Please submit your delivery info.</h1>
<label>Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name">
<label>Address:</label> <input type="text" name="address">
<label>Phone:</label> <input type="text" name="phone">
<label>Money: </label><input type="text" name="money" value='<?php echo $_SESSION['price']; ?>'/>
<label>Feedback:</label> <input type="text" name="feedback">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you show us the form code please and your attempt

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript for the data validation at the client side and notify client if he/she has entered data in wrong way.

And when you have to submit the data to the database then you need a server side 
scripting language such as PHP or node.js (framework of javascript).

Now your problem is how to show the receipt to the user. Then first you have to access the price of each item in the php and redirect to next page with some parameters in the given form.

```
$_SESSION['user_detail']=array();
$_SESSION['user_detail'][]=$meal1;
$_SESSION['user_detail'][]=$meal2;
```

and then compute the total at next page by accessing the passed variables.

And for more information please elaborate your question more and post code.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need any session or cookies you can just pass the variable within the link like when the user submits the form by clicking the submit button by redirecting the user to next page you can put variable name in the link after page name like below

Answer (score 0):

You need to store a session. Once you calculate the price, store it in a session i.e $_SESSION['price'] = $price;
On the second form, simply echo $_SESSION['price']